# Can we marry on the marriage visa if I'm claiming government funding?

Tags: united-kingdom

My boyfriend (he is Turkish) and I met 15 months ago in Costa Rica while travelling in Central America. We travelled all the way up to Mexico enjoying the most amazing time together and realising how we share the dreams and hopes for our future. We plan on buying land and having a farm.

In Mexico we found out we were having a baby. We decided maybe we could stay in this part of the world. But then we came back to Europe. I lived off my savings for a while but came to Turkey to be with him.

We want to be together and we want to get married so we can raise our little boy in England for a while before coming back to Turkey and then eventually back travelling the world.

When I go back to England I will have no more money and will have to claim benefits. Just for a short while, until either he can be here to work or I will work. Or both will work once baby is 6 months.

Can we get married if I'm on funding? And how can he get the spouse visa as I haven't worked for 18 months in the UK?

Comment: You will almost certainly fail under the financial rules, which say that you must earn more than £18,000 annually plus an additional amount per child - certain benefits can be taken into account, but you must still meet the threshold. https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/636618/Appendix_FM_1_7_Financial_Requirement_Final.pdf

Comment: The above was regarding spouse visa.

Comment: @moo any reason that's a comment and not an answer? Seems complete to me.